# How to report bugs for Google Scholar?

Tags: citations, google-scholar

I have [a paper published in 2021](https://scholar.google.hu/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=hu&user=BeUpXY0AAAAJ&citation_for_view=BeUpXY0AAAAJ:kNdYIx-mwKoC.). However, for some odd reason, Google Scholar lists citations from papers that were published years before mine, which means it's impossible they cited my paper. Where can I report this bug for Google?

For those who still not understand my question, here is a snapshot from Google Scholar:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I don't know what is unclear in my question. Google scholar lists citations which appeared before 2021, and therefore these citations cannot be related to my paper.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the problem with this particular paper is Google Scholar thinks two different papers are actually different versions of the same paper:
[image: 'All 45 versions']

If you click on the "All 45 versions" link, you'll see the paper you're concerned with, "The HITRAN2020 molecular spectroscopic database," is considered another version of "The HITRAN2016 Molecular Spectroscopic Database," which is another paper, albeit one with a very similar title, the same first author, and the same journal. The "HITRAN2016" paper is the one all those citations are pointing to, not your "HITRAN2020" paper.

If you go to your Scholar profile, you should be able to split these. It's hard for me to replicate personally, but if you click on the title of the paper in your profile, you should see an "Edit" button:

[image]

When I do that, it gives me the option to change basic metadata about the publication, but at the bottom is a list of "Scholar articles" that are all combined into one profile publication. I think this is what you're looking for:

[image: Option to split versions into multiple papers]

Comment: Thank you very much for posting an answer. I can see the 45 different versions associated to my paper. Of these versions, the first one (which is the correct version) has all of the 2143 citations. Unfortunately, a large number of these citations appeared earlier than my paper. So I do not think that removing all the other versions would solve my problem.

Comment: That's surprising! So not only is Google Scholar combining two different publications, but it's assigning citations to the wrong version! You'd think that wouldn't happen, especially with different DOIs issued to each one. It's possible selecting the "Unmerge this article" option might trigger something internally that will re-evaluate the citations? It probably won't help, but it's notoriously difficult to contact anyone at Google, especially for projects like these.

Comment: I would try to get contact with them, but I don't know where I can report bugs.

Comment: Doesn't this answer affect only articles when they are viewed through this specific profile?